For some reason the -threads option for ffmpeg is being ignored
All I'm trying to do is restrict this process to a single core, assuming there won't be a reduction in quality beyond what I could expect while multi-threading, but for some reason it's still using 100% of my CPU. Here is my command:
for %f IN (*.mkv) DO start /b /low /wait ffmpeg -i "%f" -threads 1 -c:v libx265 -crf 30 -preset superfast -c:a copy ../%~nf.mkv


You can use -x265-params pools=1 instead, but I can't tell if ultimately that is really what you want.

Yes, thank you, it works! Now I can use FFMPEG in a sort of "background mode" if I like. I did also find a bug report about this issue: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3730 it mentioned this solution.
